# Passing the Select<> to a Method

Tags: c#, linq

I have the code

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100)
          .Select(x => x / 10)
```

Is there a way I can pass the line .Select(x => x / 10) to a method. The intention is to pass the results to a method as the select happens. I want to avoid a foreach here.

Comment: I'm not sure, what you want, but can't you use a delegate to pass it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100)
          .Select(x => { var r = x / 10; foo(r); return r; })
```

If you don't want to consume the results, you really should use foreach:

```
foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(100, 100))
{
    foo(x / 10);
}
```

Comment: @Bob: foo is your method call.

Comment: Because you don't have a function called `foo`. It's just an placeholder for whatever code you want to invoke.

Comment: Just one more query. Is there a way I can remove 'return r'. Foo is a static void method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you not want the results? If not, why do you want to avoid `foreach`? It would be a far better choice.

Comment: Also, I wasn't suggesting you create a function called `Foo`. As I said, it's just a placeholder. You can simply replace `foo(r)` with whatever code you want to run on each iteration. If you happen to already have a function that does what you want, then just call that instead of `foo`.

Answer (score 5):

You could write your own extension method which performs an action on each item as it passes through:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WithAction<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Then depending on whether you wanted to act on the original value or the projected one, you'd write:

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100)
          .Select(x => x / 10)
          .WithAction(x => Console.WriteLine(x))
```

or

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100)
          .WithAction(x => Console.WriteLine(x))
          .Select(x => x / 10)
```

This keeps it independent of the `Select` itself. If you need it to make use of the projection, you could potentially write something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectAndAct<TSource, TResult>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TResult> projection,
     Action<TSource, TResult> action)
{
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        TResult result = projection(item);
        action(item, result);
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Enumerable.Range(100, 100)
          .SelectAndAct(x => x / 10,
                        (x, y) => Console.WriteLine("Was: {0}; Now: {1}", x, y))
```

Note that all of this violates the normal intention of LINQ to be side-effect-free. It's not *generally* a good idea to have side-effects in queries... but of course there are exceptions to every rule :)

Comment: Jon any easy way like Henk Holterman suggested. The only issue with his solution is my method returns a void.

Comment: My head is spinning because of the <><><><>

Comment: @Bob: These are easy to *use* - see the examples. You should really try to understand generics though - they'll make it far easier to grok other documentation etc.

Comment: @Bob - looks like you should be careful what you ask for, you might just get an answer...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a Push model, you can use:

```
 .Select(x => MyMethod(x / 10))
```

Comment: MyMethod returns a void UPDATE: (Oh where did that comment go which said 'Assuming MyMethod does not return a void')

Comment: I deleted my comment, because I figured you can always create a method that returns its argument, in addition to doing whatever it intends to do. That's essentially what my answer does.

Comment: When I use your method, I get an error The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Bob: Look at Marcelo's answer. Same idea but more compilable.